Formula for calculating difference between two time stamps
I have used the formula given below and at this link to calculate the time between two-time stamps for task created and task resolution. The time stamp should include hours from 7:00AM to 11:00PM.
=$C2-$B2 - (INT($C2)-INT($B2))*(1+TIME(7,0,0)-TIME(23,0,0))

However, there are few time stamps where this formula is not working.


This needs NETWORKDAYS() function! But are you using Excel 2010 or Excel 2007

Hello Mayukh using Microsoft office 365.

Try this : Get work hours between dates and times

Thanks Mayukh. Appreciate your help.
